# How to re-design my wordpress website footer like this?

Tags: css, wordpress

How make my website footer [en](https://ekasya.com) like this , I'm using WordPress and themeforest shopkeeper theme please look at image i need only highlighted area in my footer with all elements/menu .

[Only highlighted area footer i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1erD.png)

Comment: The Themeforest theme's are configurable. So, you must follow the documentation of your theme and find the right config that corresponds to your needs!

Comment: I'm using shopkeeper theme of themeforest and there is not any kind of option or documentation available there sadly! :(

Comment: Create a child-theme from your present theme and customize footer.php file in child-theme as per your requirement.